# WPF Loading Child Controls On Demand

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I have the following code:

```
<Expander Header="Expander" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="64,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Width="334">
                <Button Content="MyButton" />
            </Grid>
</Expander>
```

Basically I'm trying to make my application load the button only when the expander is expanded by the user. The reason why I'm doing this is that my application will have a number of expanders and each expander will host many UI controls. If I load all at once my application will quickly run out of memory so I want to make expander load its child controls only when the user expands it.

Would setting the visibility to Collapsed on load then visible when user expands do the trick?

Edit: UI Virtualization is not an option here because I need pixel based scrolling (which will be disabled if I turned UI virtualization on).

Comment: `my application will have a number of expanders and each expander will host many UI controls` - You're looking for a Virtualizing ItemsControl. WPF already has that, don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to add. UI Virtualization is not an option here because I need pixel based scrolling (which will be disabled if I turned UI virtualization on).

Comment: Is .Net 4.5 an option for you? it supports pixel-based virtualized UIs

Comment: Unfortunately not. My project is targeting .NET 4.0 and upgrading to .NET 4.5 is not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity of this example, lets decouple the contents of your expander to a some User control.

```
<!--MyUserControl will contain: -->
 <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Width="334">
      <Button Content="MyButton" />
 </Grid>
```

Now you can choose only add that content dynamically:

```
<Expander Expanded="OnExpanded"/>

 private void OnExpanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    var expander = (Expander)sender;

    if(expander.IsExpanded)
        if (expander.Content == null)
            expander.Content = new MyUserControl();
 }
```